# How to generate a single object from two tables in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to generate a single object from two tables in hibernate ?

I have two tables

1. Question table
2. options table

```
Question table
----------------
questionId | question 
--------------------
 1         | who invented java ?
 2         | who invented computer ?


 Options table
 --------------

  OptionId | option |questionId
 ------------------------------
  1       | santos | 1
  2       | james  | 1
  3       | jashuwa| 1
  4       | jhon   | 1
  5       | charles| 2
  6       | ram    | 2
  7       | raj    | 2
  8       | rohit  | 2
```

Now, I have a VO object like below

class QuestionAndOptions {

```
String questionId;
String question;
Sting option1Id;
String option1;
Sting option2Id;
String option2;
Sting option3Id;
String option3;
Sting option4Id;
String option4;

//getter and setter methods
```

}

Now, How can i create a QuestionAndOptions object using hibernate ?

Now, How can i create a list of QuestionAndOptions objects using hibernate ?

Any idea how i should this make ?

Comment: which version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: @AlexMalinovskiy I am using hibernate 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on provided tables graph I can see that relationship between Question table and Options table is one-to-many. So for your case objects will be following:

```java
@Table(name="QUESTION")
public class Question{
    @Id
    @Column(...)
    private Long questionId;
    @Column(...)
    private String questionText;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question")
    private List<Option> options
//getters and setters
}

@Table(name="OPTION")
public class Option{
    @Id
    @Column(...)
    private Long optionId;
    @Column(...)
    private String optionText;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Question question;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you !

I understood your idea. 
I know how to persist these objects through one to many mapping in hibernate.

But i don't know how to retrieve those objects from database using hibernate.

And i would like to display these question and options as a table in JSP

Comment: so in order to retrieve particular question by ID you can use following method from session factory - `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Question.class, <id>)`.

Comment: I need option object along with question object when i load question class as you suggested. Is that possible ?

Comment: so in my approach, if you load question object then options related to this question will be loaded lazily. That means that only ids of related options will be available but when you start iterating through the list of options they will be fully instantiated.

Comment: Please try and let me know if it works. If it works then please accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your table structure it looks like QuestionId is a foreign key in Options table and there is a one-to-many relationship between Question and options. Hibernate classes for this can be as follows -

```
class Option{
    String optionId;
    String option;
    Question question;
} 

class Question{
    String questionId;
    String question;
    Set<Option> options;
}
```

The QuestionAndOptions structure mentioned by you might be a little hard to maintain. You can obviously have some code to transform the hibernate objects retrieved into the structure you wish.